# JCR create single file, link from different nodes

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I am trying to create a single file node for an image with name (say A.gif). Now, I want to re-use the file across multiple nodes. Is there a way to do this? 
As a workaround, I am re-creating file nodes for different paths in my repository, but this results in duplication of files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jackrabbit, copying a file node (or rather copying a binary property) is cheap if the [DataStore](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore) is active.

That component makes sure "large" binary properties (with a configurable size threshold IIRC) are stored once only, based on a digest of their content.

So you can in this case copy the same file node many times without having to worry about disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. However, what I would do is store the file in a single location and then reference it using a `path` property from multiple locations.

Assume that you have an the following node structure

```
-content
 - articles
  - article1
  - article2
 - images
  - image1
```

You can set on each of the articles a property named `imagePath` which points to the path of the image to display, in this case `/content/images/image1`.

Comment: hi robert, thats exactly what i am trying to do..Store file at single location and reference it from multiple locations. However, I am unable to figure out how to set "path" from multiple locations?

Comment: Also, I use the identifier (node.getIdentifier()) as that doesnt change. This means you can move/change the path to your image without having to change all the references.

Answer (score 0):

And just for completeness, don't forget [references](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/3_Repository_Model.html#3.8%20Referenceable%20Nodes).

```
Node imageNode = rootNode.addNode("imageNode");
imageNode.addMixin(JcrConstants.MIX_REFERENCEABLE);

Node node1 = rootNode.addNode("1");
node1.setProperty("image", imageNode);

Node node2 = rootNode.addNode("2");
node2.setProperty("image", imageNode);

session.save();

PropertyIterator references = imageNode.getReferences();
while (references.hasNext()) {
    Property reference = references.nextProperty();
    System.out.println(reference.getPath());
}
```

Comment: Note that references are considered harmful in David's Model ( http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DavidsModel#Rule_.235:_References_considered_harmful. ) - I personally agree with that, but opinions differ of course.

Comment: I don't use references either :) was just mentioning for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

The [nt:linkedFile](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/3_Repository_Model.html#3.7.11.3%20nt%3alinkedFile) type was made for just this kind of use.